# Voiding data on a DVD-R/DVD+R on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, installation, dvd

I asked on askubuntu and was pointed over here.

Long-story short, I had to completely format both my hard drives. So, I need to reinstall my dual-boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu. One problem. I lost my Windows 7 installation disk.

However, after a bit of searching, I found an old Ubuntu boot disk that I don't need due to it being an outdated version. The boot disk only has 793MB written to it, out of the 4.7GB a DVD offers.

This is more than enough for me to write the Windows 7 ISO to it.

Problem though. It's in DVD+R format, not DVD-RW, which means I can't format the disk.

So my question is if there is any way to delete or otherwise void the data in that sector so I can write the Windows 7 ISO to the disk without any conflicts. Anything?

Quick note: I've tried installing Win7 via USB thumbdrive, external HDD, and even SD card, with no success. That's not an option for me. It has to be in disk format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that you can not over write or delete anything burned on the disk. You can only add to it. What I would personally do is put ubuntu on the computer download VirtualBox and configure it to run on the .iso file. But you might be asking how do I get the .iso to the computer. Just put the .iso on the disc but don't format it just move the .iso to the disc. Then put it in your dic drive and copy and paste the .iso on your computer. Also before you install VirtualBox make sure you have dkms installed. (I forgot how to install dkms, i think it sudo apt-get dkms). Then configure your virtual machine to boot of the wondows ISO

Comment: HAHA typo WONDOWS ahahaha, i loled

Comment: Dont forget to get the updates (sudo apt-get update)

Comment: Also one last thing, depending on how good your computer is windows might be slightly laggy running on the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Thankfully I worked out another solution after some lengthy UEFI external HDD dickery. VMs would run alright on my PC but it wasn't really an option for me. It's all good now though.

Comment: Im glad to hear the problem is fixed :)